# Duplicated object not showing in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh, objects

My issue is that my duplicated objects are not showing.

I've tried everything, visibility options are on, turning all restriction toggles on and off, one by one, everything but I just couldn't make them show in render.

If I hold <kbd>Z</kbd> and choose the *Rendered*, the objects are showing, but when I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> , only the original model that I made shows.

Comment: Did you find the solution I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try checking Visibility in the Object Properties

[image: Object visibility]

Comment: Yea, I said all visible options are enabled

Comment: is duplicate of other object also not showing in render?

Comment: only duplicated of the model made by me